# What is the difference between static, internal and public constructors?

Tags: c#, static, constructor, access-modifiers

What is the difference between static, internal and public constructors? Why do we need to create all of them together?

```
 static xyz()
 {
 }

 public xyz()
 {
 }

 internal xyz()
 {
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to create all of them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `static` constructor will be called the first time an object of the type is instantiated or a static method is called. And will only run once

The `public` constructor is accessible to all other types

The `internal` constructor is only accessible to types in the same assembly

On top of these three there's also `protected` which is only accessible to types derived from the enclosing type

and `protected internal` which is only accessible to types in the same assembly or those that derives from the enclosing type

and `private` which is only accessible from the type itself and any nested types

Comment: protected internal which is only accessible to types in the same assembly OR derived from the enclosing type(other assembly), not "that derives...".

Answer (score 8):

The difference between `public` and `internal` is that the `internal` constructor can only be called from within the same assembly, while the `public` one can be called from other assemblies as well.

`static` is a constructor that gets called only the first time the class is referenced. Static members do not belong to an instance of the class, but "to the class itself". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx for more information about `static`.

Answer (score 4):

- Static constructor runs only ones - before the first use of the class and it can access only the static members of the class
- Public constructor runs every time when you create an object of the class using `new`
- Internal is just another access modifier for the constructor above. It can also be private as well. This is exactly the same as access modifiers for other functions.

Your code doesn't actually compile, because the internal and the public one are the same constructor with different modifiers, which you can't do. You need to pick either internal or public (or private).

Comment: public constructors don't run every time you create an object. Since the object could be created using another public constructor or a constructor with another access modifier. It's also possible to create an object without `new`. When you box a valuetype you create an object but don't use new

Answer (score 4):

The static constructor is called the first time the **type** is used. Either in a static context or by creating an instance.

All other constructors are called when a **new instance** is created. The modifier just determines which code can create an instance.

If your constructor is private only the class itself and nested types can create an instance (maybe in a static factory method). This works like public/private/internal on methods.

Comment: privates are also exposed to nested types

Comment: Is there any way to force the "use" of a generic type T without constructing an instance?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can declare a static method with a generic Parameter: `public static T Get<T>()`. This way you have to specify the generic parameter when calling the method. If your class has a generic Parameter you have to specify it on the class. Like `SomeClass<T>.Do()`.

Comment: @Zebi: If a variety of classes are designed to be returned by `Factory.Get<T>`, and if the static constructor for each of them registers itself with `Factory`, then `Factory.Get<T>` will be able to operate on any such type `T` whose static constructor has run. I don't know any way other than Reflection, however, via which `Factory.Get<Foo>` can work if `Foo` lacks a public default constructor and hasn't run its public constructor. Note that merely passing `Foo` as a generic parameter, or even creating a `Foo[]`, won't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create all types of constructors. The access modifiers serve the same function as any other access modifier - to determine how the constructors can be accessed.

- a **static constructor** will be called the first time the class is accessed statically.
- a constructor with an **internal** access modifier can only be called by items that meet the criteria for `internal`, which is "accessible only within files in the same assembly".
- a constructor with an **public** access modifier can be accessed by anything
- and so on. `protected` and `private` constructors operate as you expect - the constructors are accessible to items that meet the criteria for the access modifier.